# How to rotate a marker line in a polygon ring?

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology

I've to rotate a marker line in a polygon ring by 180 degrees without rotating the same marker line at the polygon border (outline):

[image]

How can I do this in QGIS 2.18/2.99?

Comment: Have you read either of these two posts? [How to rotate symbols in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182268/how-to-rotate-symbols-in-qgis) & [Rotate marker symbols individually in QGIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216987/rotate-marker-symbols-individually-in-qgis)

Comment: I don't want to rotate markers by field values. All triangles (marker line) should be placed inside the polygon. It seems this is impossible for polygons with a ring.

Comment: I believe so as well, it's a nice feature to have. However,  it would be a property associated with multi-polygon features that identifies the outer and inner rings separately and allowing individual  manipulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could reproduce this in 2.18.3 with a scratch layer of type POLYGON, where i digitised both the outer ring (exterior) and hole (using the **add ring** tool) in a  **clockwise** direction, and applied 180 degrees to the marker rotation. (Image on left)

I was able to get the result you were after by digitising the hole in an anti-clockwise direction... (Image on right)

[image]

It doesn't happen if you create a new SHAPEFILE layer; I assume this automatically corrects the hole so that its vertices go anti-clockwise.

Just to add to the confusion, it looks like you need to use a rotation value of 0 for a MULTIPOLYGON layer..

**EDIT** tried all 4 combinations of winding for the exterior and hole. It looks like the assumption is the exterior is assumed to be clockwise and holes anti-clockwise. [This may not be the case for all formats](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/147971/55203). But provided holes use a different winding to the exterior, you should be able to get it to work.

Comment: The features are saved in a PostGIS polygon layer. I suppose that ST_ForceRHR() fixes the marker line symbology. I'll do some tests in the next days.