# Right-hand-rule in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, vector, geometry, direction

It seems that there isn't a plugin to perform the right-hand-rule on a layer or selected features. Can this be done by using some Python code? Is there a function that works in the same way as [ST_ForceRHR](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForceRHR.html)?

Comment: Describe what that plugin would do.

Comment: It should correct the direction of vertices: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227178/77061

Comment: I would guess that saving the layer would correct the direction. Winding rules in shapefiles and for example in GeoJSON are just opposite, though. What QGIS does internally may be yet another story.

Comment: There are two interpretations about the round hand rule in GIS. Would you like to have outer rings clockwise or counterclockwise?

Comment: Outer ring vertices should go clockwise and inner ring vertices should go counterclockwise. Scratch layers are not corrected automatically when saving edits.

Comment: Ok, that's the shapefile way. Right arm is inside the polygon when walking the path. The other rule is looking at the fingers of the right hand, they wind anticlockwise. What practical problem do you have due to not uniform windings?

Comment: Marker lines are not placed properly: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/227103/77061

Comment: what happens if you try **v.clean** in GRASS (using Processing)? I found it enforced shapefile windings, but your mileage may vary depending on the type of layer.

Answer (score 9):

Use QGIS expressions with [`force_rhr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#force-rhr) function: simply use `force_rhr( $geometry)` using Menu Processing > Toolbox > [Geometry by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression).

Answer (score 6):

Since QGIS 3.4.3 there is [`QgsGeometry().forceRHR()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsGeometry.html#qgis.core.QgsGeometry.forceRHR) as Python equivalent. You can use it as follows:

```py
polygons = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('polygon')[0]

with edit(polygons):
    for feature in polygons.getFeatures():
        rhrgeom = feature.geometry().forceRHR() # forceRHR() returns a geometry
        feature.setGeometry(rhrgeom) # To actually change the geometry, use setGeometry
        polygons.updateFeature(feature) # Dont forget to "save" these changes
```