Forcing QGIS to export using left hand rule
I've downloaded some polygons to import them into a SQL Server geography instance for some testing. My issue is that every time I export them to a .csv file using QGIS 3.36.3, the Polygons are output using the Right hand rule and SQL Server requires polygons to use the Left hand rule.
I have downloaded every data set available from https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/8e3a4564-8081-42ec-8772-03ade11d4acf/local-authority-boundaries-scotland and https://boundaries.scot/boundary-maps/data-files but every dataset that I download outputs in the same way. I have looked on every online resource I can find and have found that I'm able to force the right hand rule using the processing toolbox in QGIS, and have also found what appear to be many other different ways to force the output to RHR, but I haven't found anything to force the LHR.
SQL Server has the facility to reorient polygons to use the LHR, but this doesn't work on Multipolygons - and there are too many sub-polygons in the dataset for me to be able to pull out each individual polygon to correct them.
Is there a (reasonably) simple way within QGIS of forcing the LHR, or reorienting the polygons so that SQL is happy with the data I'm trying to import into it?

Left-hand rule and Right-hand rules are not always understood in the same way. Do you mean this left-hand rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-types-overview?view=sql-server-ver16 " if you imagine yourself walking along the ring of a geography Polygon, following the points in the order in which they are listed, the area on the left is being treated as the interior of the Polygon, and the area on the right as the exterior of the Polygon"? Thus, the outer ring goes counter-clockwise https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ForcePolygonCCW.html

Import directly into server from QGis, don't go via another format

Try Reverse line direction: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisreverselinedirection then convert lines to polygons.

There is a way to reverse the polygons directly without turning them into linestrings and back. QGIS has a function "polygon_force_ccw" https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#force-polygon-ccw for that purpose.

Forces a geometry to respect the convention where exterior rings are
counter-clockwise, interior rings are clockwise.

Shapefiles use the clockwise orientation for the outer rings. That the source data follows that convention can be checked with ogrinfo
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_IsPolygonCCW(geometry) from SP_regions_1999_2011" SP_regions_1999_2011.shp
INFO: Open of `SP_regions_1999_2011.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 8
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
ST_IsPolygonCCW(geometry): Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  ST_IsPolygonCCW(geometry) (Integer) = 0
...

Confirmed that the polygons are not counter-clockwise.
Then open the data with QGIS and create a new layer with the "Geometry by expression" tool. Use expression "force_polygon_ccw($geometry)".

Save the new layer into CSV and check the result with ogrinfo.
ogrinfo -dialect SQLite -sql "select ST_IsPolygonCCW(geom_WKT) from ccw" ccw.csv
INFO: Open of `ccw.csv'
      using driver `CSV' successful.

Layer name: SELECT
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 8
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
ST_IsPolygonCCW(geom_WKT): Integer (0.0)
OGRFeature(SELECT):0
  ST_IsPolygonCCW(geom_WKT) (Integer) = 1

OGRFeature(SELECT):1
  ST_IsPolygonCCW(geom_WKT) (Integer) = 1
...

The polygons in the CSV file are now counter-clockwise.
I did not test a Python way, but with a small modification to this answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/412670/30184 it should be easy.

That's amazing! Thank you so much for your help!

Huge thanks to Babel for suggesting reverse line direction.
Converting the polygons to lines, reversing direction and then converting those lines back into Polygons worked perfectly and even a luddite like me was able to do it without causing any chaos.
